# PHP - preg_match() - matching substitution character black diamond with question mark

Tags: php, regex, character, preg-match, special-characters

I have a problem with substitution character - diamond question mark � in text I'm reading with SplFileObject. This character is already present in my text file, so nothing can't be done to convert it to some other encoding. I decided to search for it with preg_match(), but the problem is that PHP can't find any occurence of it. PHP probably sees it as different character as �. I don't want to just remove this character from text, so that's the reason I want to search for it with preg_match(). Is there any way to match this character in PHP?

I tried with regex line: `/.�./i`, but without success.

Comment: Try `preg_match('/\x{FFFD}/u', s, $matches);`. Or check the character code using [encoding conversion tool](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/).

Comment: @stribizhev it is U+FFFD (check with tool you suggested), but it's still unrecognized by PHP - preg_match() or preg_replace()

Comment: What you see is not what the character actually is. You should inspect a hex dump of the data to see the original byte that causes PHP to print out the replacement character.

Comment: Please check [this snippet](https://eval.in/404252) showing how to obtain the correct hex code. It will be easy when you find what the right symbol is.

Comment: @nhahtdh checked the text file and there is "ef bf bd" in hex notation which is the same as U+FFFD. It's weird that PHP recognizes this as "93" in hex notation - checked with snippet from stribizhev.

Comment: @stribizhev tried your snippet and it didn't work correctly - I got back array with string with complete text, not by parts as in your case. So instead of it I rewrite this foreach with for and mb_strlen() function. Then I came to "93" and "94" which are represented with question mark. So I tried to preg_match() with '/\x{0093}/u' and '/\x{0094}/u' and again nothing like before. I only get empty array as result.

Comment: Perhaps, you can also try `'/\x93\x94/'` or `'/\x{9394}/'`.

Comment: @stribizhev yes, '\x93' alone works, but both 93 and 94 in the form you wrote, don't. So I changed to '/(?|\x93|\x94)/' and now gets both. What is the difference between \x93, \x{93} and \x{0093} ?

Comment: Interesting, so [`(?|(\x93)|(\x94))`](https://regex101.com/r/sH1fA6/1) works, right? `\x93` and `\x94` are separate code points, and thus can be matched as alternatives. It is actually the same as [`\x{93}|\x{94}`](https://regex101.com/r/sH1fA6/2) and [`\x{0093}|\x{0094}`](https://regex101.com/r/sH1fA6/3). The difference is in the notation only. Is that an answer, BTW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP with SplFileObject seems to read the file a little bit different and instead of U+FFFD detects U+0093 and U+0094. If you are having the same problem as I had, then I suggest you to use hexdump to get information on how unrecognized character is encoded in it. Afterwards I suggest you to use [this snippet](https://eval.in/404252) as recommended by @stribizhev in comments, to get hex code recognized by PHP. Once you figure out what is correct hex code of unrecognized character (use [conversion tool](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) as suggested by @stribizhev in comments, to get correct value), you can use preg_...() function. Here's the solution to my problem:

```
preg_replace("/(?|\x93|\x94)/i", "'", $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.Hexadecimal of � character is FFFD

```
$line = "�";
if (preg_match("/\x{FFFD}/u", $line, $match))
  print "Match found!";
```